# Add HTML tags to HTMLAgilityPack nodes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, html-agility-pack

I need to parse through a CMS generated HTML page and add list item tags around any HTMLAgiligyPack  nodes with a child  node that have a name attribute of "Example".

**C# code**

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.htm");
foreach (HtmlNode docObjects in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//object[@type='text/sitemap']"))
{
  HtmlNodeCollection paramNodes = docObjects.ChildNodes;
  foreach (HtmlNode paramNode in paramNodes)
  {
    string paramName = paramNode.GetAttributeValue("name", null);
    string paramValue = paramNode.GetAttributeValue("value", null);
    HtmlNode findItem = paramNode.NextSibling;
    if (paramName == "Example")
    {
     //Add listitem (<li>) tags to the paramName node 
    }
  }
}
```

**test.htm**

```
<OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Example" value="Help.chm::\toc.hhc">
</OBJECT>
<OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Example" value="Help2.chm::\toc.hhc">
</OBJECT>
<OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Example" value="Help3.chm.chm::\toc.hhc">
</OBJECT>
```

needs to be

```
<li><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Example" value="Help.chm::\testing.htm">
</OBJECT></li>
<li><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Example" value="Help2.chm::\testing.htm">
</OBJECT></li>
<li><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Example" value="Help3.chm::\testing.htm">
</OBJECT></li>
```

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. This is part of a bigger project I'm working on and will likely be requesting help with in the future. Need a crash course back into C# - thanks you all ahead of time.

Comment: Also, your description of what you want and the example you posted do not agree with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way (code goes within your `if` clause):

```
var objectNode = paramNode.ParentNode;
var li = doc.CreateElement("li");
objectNode.Remove();
li.AppendChild(objectNode);

doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(li);
```

Comment: that worked! It looks like if the code is ran twice, HAP generates a set of completely empty li tags.. It also tries creating the closing tags of CMS generated listitems that use poor formatting, but I don't need the closing tags.  Possible to stop HAP from auto=generating closing tags?